# Inno Setup - Retrieve custom values

Tags: inno-setup

I have created a custom page in inno setup. It has 5 textboxes each for a specific purpose. I want to retrieve the values (as entered by the user) in the script for doing additional work, such as registering, creation of folders, etc... 
Can anyone please suggest on how to retrieve the values in the script for the custom page and controls?

Answer (score 4):

You should have a look at the sample script `CodeDlg.iss` that is intalled with Inno Setup. I suppose that you use the [`CreateInputQueryPage`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/) function to create your custom page with the five text boxes, as in `CodeDlg.iss`:

```
UserPage := CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome,
  'Personal Information', 'Who are you?',
  'Please specify your name and the company for whom you work, then click Next.');
UserPage.Add('Name:', False);
UserPage.Add('Company:', False);
```

Then you use

```
UserPage.Values[0]
```

to access the value of the first edit box, `UserPage.Values[1]` to access the data of the second, and so on.

Comment: What if i want to add a new button on this inputquery page?

Comment: chirag, you can make use of create button and assign the necessory co-ordinates..  something like this. ConnectButton := TButton.Create(WizardForm);
  ConnectButton.Parent := WizardForm;
  ConnectButton.Left := 8;
  ConnectButton.Top := WizardForm.ClientHeight -
    ConnectButton.ClientHeight - 8;
  ConnectButton.Caption := 'Connect';
  ConnectButton.OnClick := @ConnectButtonClick;